# CSS: float:left with a margin-right doesn't push all elements away

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like all my content to flow around an image. To do this, I simply did

```
img#me {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

This works for text wraping, but other elements go behind it. For example

```
<style>
h2 {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
</style>
<img id="me" src="http://paultarjan.com/paul.jpg" />
<h2>Things!</h2>
```

Then the `h2` background flows right past the `30px` margin. How should I do this instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wish I could explain why exactly, but

```
h2 {
   ...
   overflow: hidden;
   ...
}
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I'm pretty sure it comes from the `h2` being a `block` element. If it works for you, the easiest cure would be making it `display: inline`. Otherwise, give the `h2` a specific width, and a `float: left`, as well.

Comment: If I make them inline, then they don't extend all the way to the right. I just want the HTML to do as it normally would, except to have a 330px empty area to the left

Comment: @Paul I see! Hmm, that's tricky, seeing as this needs to be dynamic, right? It should only behave that way if it's next to your image but not if it's underneath, correct?

Comment: Exactly. If it is under the image, I want it to have the full width. I didn't expect this to be hard! ;)

Comment: @Paul let us know whether Les' answer sorts it! I'm interested to know the outcome.

Comment: Yup, overflow fixed it! That sounds like it should be the default behavior, but CSS is a weird beast. http://paultarjan.com/